# How to find just starting OpenSource project and Join or find programmers for own?

Tags: open-source, project, teamwork

Is there any place on the web where can I join a team when they are just starting their project?

Is there any place where developers can make groups for projects?

I know there are some /dev/forums where you can have luck to find something interesting in some topic ... but the chances there are really low.

I know that you can find some projects on CodePlex or GitHub but they will be already started projects and it's not so easy to understand and join it ...

I want to find some place where new ideas comes to new teams.

So ... maybe starting project must already have a good base, but not to big base and then project leader must Promote it and find developers who like the idea ?

Sometimes that is really hard to catch such promotions.

Comment: I've often wished a website like this existed.

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132343/where-do-i-find-collaborators-for-hobby-projects/132353

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to start your own, put it out there, then try and recruit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find a good open source project to join?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/294/how-can-i-find-a-good-open-source-project-to-join) and of [Where do I find collaborators for hobby projects](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/132343/where-do-i-find-collaborators-for-hobby-projects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure a website like this could exist. Everyone on the team would have a different idea of what they want the project to be. Finding a number of people interested in the same thing at the same time whilst everyone had free time would not often happen. People would jump the gun and start implementing before the team had decided that it was big enough to start.

Your best bet is to find a project that is just starting out or to start your own project.

Comment: Thank you for your toughs but not , I would be happy to join some interesting project from it's start and also I will be happy to find some developers for some my ideas, really there is nothing that can block my wish.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell what you're asking here, but it sounds very much like what you want is somewhere between sourceforge.net and brainstorm.ubuntu.com.

If you want ideas for a project of your own, look at some of the feature requests on brainstorm.ubuntu.com, decide which ones need to be implemented at an application level and set about implementing them.

If you want to join a small team of other developers, look at the Help Wanted section on sf.net (though I've had some difficulty finding it recently with their new site, it is still indexed by Google).  Those projects vary wildly in maturity and complexity (and team size) but it's the best-fit solution to what I think your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Code52](http://www.code52.org)?  They start a new project each week so you can get in at the start and see a project through to the end.  Code52 is the brainchild of a few Australian developers but anyone can pitch in and help with each project.  In fact, each week they post a recap post showing, amongst other things, the number of contributors and there are always more than 10 contributors.

Don't be put off by the 1 week schedule; a lot can be accomplished in that time frame and you can always continue to work on them after.

You can also make suggestions for future projects and the most popular ones are the ones which are chosen.  If you have a particular idea, post it [here](http://code52.uservoice.com/forums/143105-code-52) and drum up support for it!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to start up a place like this. I see you already have a website. You could allow people to create profiles etc. I promise I will join!
Maybe a platform where everyone can

- present what they are working on (if they already do),
- talk about ideas & plans they have for the future
- where or in what way they think other people could contribute and how much effort there would be to familiarize with the project before the fun can begin

You could start up with something simple, in the sense that it does not require you so much time to set up, and if people show some interest improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check on Likedin groups related to programming language, such as ruby on rails, python, or any other popular open source language. I've already got the chance to see people inviting others to participate on their new open source projects, and what was good about it was that the person looking for new members actually expected inexperienced ones that would learn using his project.

Another option is google groups, yahoo groups related to a particular language. Depending on where you are located you might find up they are meeting to practice coding (specially coding dojo practitioners) and they might have people starting on open source projects as well.

[Ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/) can provide you a quick view on projects that are being tracked, the amount of users and how long the project was up based on the code repository. While I find unlike that you will find an open source project being tracked as soon as it is started, you may find it useful to know of smaller open source communities.

Finally, looking for projects that have been recently forked may also help as well. [Nightgale](http://getnightingale.com/) was forked from Songbird, a popular open source player that ended support for linux community users. They just released their full release. Something similar happened to foswiki few years ago, so this is a topic that might help you find starting projects that are promising.